# Does tensorflow calculate the common ops in different fetches again and again?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

An extreme case of what i am trying to ask is :

```
tf.Session().run(fetches = [a,a], feed_dict = feed_dict)
```

does tensorflow here run the same computations twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, tensorflow will compute only what you request, no more and no less. If two computations depend on the same bit of code, for example two loss functions depending on the same neural network core, the core will not be computed twice. On the flip side of that note that if an OP in tensorflow is *not* needed to perform a computation, tensorflow will *not* compute it. This is the magic that the tensorflow dependency graph provides.

Note also that between calls to `sess.run` any OPs (operations) will be re-computed because OPs are not stored between calls to `sess.run`, the only thing that remains between calls to `sess.run` are variables.

Comment: you are right .. i ran three fetches in three different sessions one after the other. [loss],  [optimizer, loss], [loss]. loss was same in first and second and different in third